# Up to date xcode OAUTH example?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, oauth

I've created an iPhone app (IOS6.1) which, among other things, uses my Twitter user_timeline to fetch the news-messages into a tableview. Which worked fine until Twitter decided to implement API v1.1 which requires OAUTH in order to get any results.
Since I'm not a "real" developer, this goes beyond my knowledge. I did search for information, but all is outdated or not relevant for my needs. I need automatic login without any user-input, just when you tap the 'News'-icon in my app, the messages should appear/refresh.

So my question is, is there any good example available which shows me how to implement OAUTH this way? And are there libraries which are ARC compatible/up-to-date?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has some nice examples of Oauth over here: http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth/